# how to define a variable in jQuery from ajax/php query

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a text field and when I enter text into it, a search is done on the database via php/ajax.

The result looks like this:

```
echo "<li data-lost-id='".$lostId."'>" . $lost_time_desc. "</li>";
```

I want to put $lostId into a variable in jQuery but I can't figure out how.

I tried this:

```
 var $lostId = $(this).data('lost-id');
      console.log($lostId);
```

but console shows me "undefined".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.attr()` to get the value from a custom tag attribute.

```
var lostId = $(theLiElement).attr('data-lost-id');
```

Or you can echo the PHP variable directly into a js variable.

```
var lostId = '<?php echo $lostId; ?>';
```

Comment: Nice one! Thanks a lot